# How to save the name of the image from an input file

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a field type `string` called `image_cover` on my database.
I have a field type `file` on my form:

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->create($event, ['type' => 'file'])
    echo $this->Form->file('image_cover')
    echo $this->Form->submit('Send')
  echo $this->Form->end()
?>
```

On controller `$this->request->data('image_cover')` is an array with file name, size etc.

I need the value of the `image_cover` change to only the name of the file.

I'm trying do this on `beforeSave` but is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, but the easiest to understand is to have an input field that is not part of the schema of your table. For example, instead of `image_cover` you could have `image_file`:

```
 echo $this->Form->file('image_file');
```

Make sure you set `image_file` in the `$_accessible` list of fields of your entity. You will be able to access this field in `beforeSave` so you can store it.

There is this plugin that will do exactly that for you: https://github.com/davidyell/CakePHP3-Proffer